# Winter Bash 2016 Skeptics challenge!

Tags: discussion

As you might have noticed, some user avatars have funny hats or masks. As every year, for Christmas, the Stack Exchange team creates a fun competition to get hats awarded for completing fun (or secret) challenges.

If you want to know more, [a useful introduction has been added to youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U&feature=youtu.be)

Can you figure out how the Skeptics site has been referenced in it?

Please join our Winter Bash and have fun!

Comment: Is that a hat, or are you wearing a bag over your face? ;)

Comment: @JasonR it's an Alien Spork facehugger. I thought it was obvious.

Comment: referenced? The blog post mentioned you as a hat team member, does that count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I believe I have it

https://youtu.be/CDi_nj1-G6U?t=1m17s

[image]

It says

> Does being cold increase your chances of catching the common cold?

Then here:

> [Does being cold increase your chances of catching the common cold?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/88/does-being-cold-increase-your-chances-of-catching-the-common-cold)

Comment: I see Tinfoil hats, Commonly associated with Conspiracy theory people, which, worded another way, are skeptical of the common beliefs of modern society (usually what the government says is the truth)